# Plotting 3D Chessboard/Swiss Cheese Type Patterns in Python

Tags: python, plot, 3d

My particular case is that I am trying to make a 3D space-time diagram of a 2D cellular automata. If anybody has any advice/clever ways of representing this visually that would be awesome, but to make the question more general I'll phrase it as...

**What is the best way to plot a sort of 3D chessboard or Swiss Cheese type pattern where the white squares are transparent (or vice versa)?**

I have looked around and have found ways to plot Imshow type plots on a 3D coordinate system, but it was kind of clunky, slow, and I couldn't get the transparency to work (didn't try masks, but it didn't seem like what I wanted, but I could be wrong).

I have also used a scatter plot where I have a point at (x,y,z) if cell (x,y) is in the active state at time z (also tried the other way around...). This actually managed to render and looked pretty cool, but for the wrong reasons since it was hard to see anything on and was hard to angle properly due to the amount of points on the scatter plots making it lag.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: what library / tool are you using to make the plots?

Comment: Right now I'm using mplot3d's Axes3d. But I was wondering in general what people would use to plot something that fills so much space.